# inserting a layout into another layout using its id in android

Tags: android

I have a relative layout defined in a xml file(say realtive.xml). In another layout I have a relativelayout tag inside a linearlayout(say linear.xml). This realtive layout is empty and has an id say "rl". On clicking a button in linear.xml, I want the contents of relative.xml to be set in the relative layout with id "rl". 
How should this be done?

Comment: i think u can use 'include' tag and u can simply include a layout file in another layout.and u can hide this included layout as u wish...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `onClick()` method for that `Button` inflate the new layout and add it to that empty `RelativeLayout`:

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl);
getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.realtive, rl, true);
```

Also if you don't want to add the parent `RelativeLayout` from `realtive.xml` to the empty `RelativeLayout` then use the `merge` tag:

*realtive.xml*

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <!-- Here is the content of the realtive.xml without the parent RelativeLayout-->
</merge>
```

Here you can read more about the `merge` tag: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html

Answer (score 1):

Inflate the new layout and add to RelativeLayout
getLayoutInflater().inflate(resource, root, attachToRoot);